# VueJS list rendering anomaly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I already read some similar topics about my problem, but still I can’t figure out, what can be the problem is.
Long story short, I have an array of objects, and these objects also have an array, called “**messages**”. The parent object has some additional data, and my problem is caused by the child array, the **messages**.

The problem is:
The **messages** array is filled up by the server. After it, I successfully render a list of it’s content, show it on the web page, so far so good. But as soon as a new data arrives from the server, the rendered list is not updating itself. I checked the array’s content via the Vue dev plugin, and the new message was there, but the rendered list still remained in it’s original state.

The twist in the story is, that I created a simple test array, which is very similar to the original one, and also rendered on the page. When a new message arrives, I push it to both of them, and to my surprise, each one is updating itself perfectly. For the sake of curiosity, I commented out the test array rendering, and believe it or not, the original array does not update itself anymore on the page. After I remove the commented test array render, both of them works again.

The vue component:

```
/**
 * Root
 */

import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

import inputComponent from './chat/input.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#chat-root',
    components: { inputComponent },
    data() {
        return {
            userID: document.getElementById('user').value,
            ready: false,
            roomID: "",
            roomInstances: [],
            test: [
                {
                    messages: []
                }
            ],
            pollTime: 5000
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('chat/init')
            .then(resp => {
                this.roomID = resp.data.roomList[0]._id
                this.roomInstances = resp.data.roomList
                this.fetchMessagesFromServer()
                this.poll()
                this.heartBeat()
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    },
    computed: {
        getMessages() {
            return this.roomInstance.messages
        },
        roomInstance() {
            return this.roomInstances.filter(i => i.id = this.roomID)[0]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setRoom(id) {
            if (this.roomID === id)
                return
            this.roomID = id
        },
        fetchMessagesFromServer() {
            axios.get(`chat/get/${this.roomID}`)
                .then(resp => {
                    this.roomInstance.messages = resp.data.messages
                    this.ready = true
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        },
        heartBeat() {
            setInterval(() => axios.get(`heartbeat/${this.userID}`), this.pollTime - 1000)
        },
        poll() {
            axios.create({ timeout: this.pollTime })
                .get(`poll/${this.userID}`).then(resp => {
                    if (resp.data.data) {
                        this.roomInstance.messages.push(resp.data.data.message)
                        this.test[0].messages.push(resp.data.data.message)
                    }
                    this.poll()
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    }
})
```

Template:

```
extends base

block scripts
    script(src="/dist/chat.bundle.js")

block content

    #chat-root(style="margin-top: 50px" v-cloak)

        // Hack! Supposed to be an axios request?
        input(v-if="false" id="user" value=`${user._id}`)

        input-component(:room="roomID")

        p {{ roomID || "Whoo hooo hoooo!" }}

        span(v-for="room in roomInstances" @click="setRoom(room._id)") {{ room.name }} | 

        div(v-if="ready")
            div(v-for="message in getMessages")
                p {{ message }}
            hr
            div(v-for="fe in test[0].messages")
                p {{ fe }}
```

Comment: please include your code in the post itself instead of just linking to it

Comment: Thanks, fixed. :)

Comment: as @thanksd said you should make `roomInstance.message` reactive and always add `key` to `v-for`

Comment: @TomaszKostuch binding a `key` with `v-for` is really only necessary when using `v-for` with a component tag.

Comment: You are right :) Thank you, I forgot about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you are not finding the `roomInstance` correctly in the function for that computed property. You should just use the `find` method and return `i.id === this.roomID` in the callback instead of `i.id = this.roomID`:

```
roomInstance() {
  return this.roomInstances.find(i => i.id === this.roomID);
}
```

The other issue might be when you are setting `roomInstance.messages` in the `axios.get().then` callback. If `roomInstance.messages` is `undefined` at that point, you'll need to use the [`Vue.set` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) (aliased on the Vue instance via `this.$set`) in order to make that property reactive:

```
this.$set(this.roomInstance, 'messages', resp.data.messages)
```

[Here's the Vue documentation on Change Detection Caveats.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: I fixed the code based on your suggestion, thank you! However, I face to a new issue, which says: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'messages' in undefined.

Comment: I solved the "undefnied" problem, it was my fault.
this.$set saves the day.